# Iphone like password interface

Tags: iphone

I am new to Iphone programming. I want to add a password module to my application with look and feel as iphone's "Enter Passcode". Is it possible. I earlier tried this by using four text boxes and allowing allowing to enter only one alphabet in each.

---

This had the problem of cursor in the text boxes. So i disabled all these, took an invisible text box. Allowed user to enter passcode in it. And copied the text in each of those disable text box on textediting event. This works as required. However the last text box of the four never displays text. Is this because i have chosen text editing event. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Google Code project that has implemented this pretty nicely:

http://code.google.com/p/kpasscode/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did get the code. However i was unable to integrate it in my application.I tried to add the controller as view on click of a button. No success.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the 4 number pin pad?

I implemented something similar

[image]

xib file with 12 UIButtons 4 UILabels and 4 UIImageViews.

Comment: No, but I implemented it very trivial. For each button tap increase the value of a counter. Judging on the counter value set a UILabel to "•". When the counter is 4 I tell my delegate that the pin was entered. For each cancel I decrease the counter. when the counter is -1 I tell my delegate to cancel. When the counter is 0 I show "Cancel" if it's higher I show the delete symbol. Nothing fancy. maybe kpasscode from code.google will fulfill your needs in a ready to use solution

Comment: Yep, it all makes sense to me. Just wanted to flush out a bit more details for the original question poster.